# How do I ignore values with empty string when passing them as a query to model.find()?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a form in the front-end that collects some data which then it sends to the back end that makes a request to a mongo database.

Server-side I created an object that stores the form data and I pass it to model.find()

I get an empty array in response when I shouldn't because some fields in the object I passed have empty strings (as not all values in form are required).

How can I have model.find() ignore queries with empty strings?

Here is what i tried:

Object to pull form values-

```
const values = {
date: req.body.date,
firstName: req.body.firstName,
lastName: req.body.lastName,
email: req.body.email,
age: req.body.age,
car: req.body.car,

};
```

I tried to iterate through values and create new object which would only contain values that are not empty-

```
const filter = {}

for (let key in values) {

if(values[key] !== '') {
filter.key = values[key]
}
}

Model.find({ filter}).then((user) =>
res.json(user)
);
```

Does not work. How else can I ignore the options with empty strings?

Comment: Might be a silly question, but are you potentially using every form input to query the model in the scenario where every form field has non-null data?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but, I have some form validation that requires at least one field to be completed before submitting, so there should always be at least one value in the query that is not empty. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `filter.key = values[key]` to `filter[key] = values[key]`

```
for (let key in values) {
    if(values[key]) {
        filter[key] = values[key];
    };
};
```

That will return a `filter` object only containing properties from the `req.body` object that are not `falsy`.

Comment: The answer I provided give you what you want: a filter object without any empty string properties. I would think that the problem is lying elsewhere in your code/design if your overall problem is still not resolved

Comment: In the front-end i have a form with field inputs for every value in values(see initial post) that i am using in order for the user to search the database for users. There are  quite a few inputs. On submit im just trying to take the users inputs and package it into a query to then send to mongo. Say i want to search for users with a red car, who speak french, etc. I want to be able to chain a query to send. Am i going about it wrong?

Comment: I can take a look at it again if you can provide more code to look over, but based on what you've provided so far, you now have the method to filter out empty properties

Comment: So after digging into my code i discovered that im sending the values over from the front-end via params, as axios get requests dont allow for body data. So i was attempting to retrieve the data from the body... I still had the same issue however, which your response does ultimately answer so i will mark it as correct. Thank you.